# Mark email as read after 30 mins in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I'm receiving a lot of emails on a daily basic. They are spread out through folders. Lot of them are just emails that are generated automaticity. Is there any way to mark them as read after 30 mins, I mean emails that are in specific folder, but applying rule to that folder. I would also like to keep default behavior, so if I got time to check them before 30 mins they are also read.

I'm using outlook in office365.

Comment: Not with the default configuration. You may be able to program a VBA macro that does this, but SuperUser is not the kind of place to ask for this, unless your VBA skills are great and only need help finding that error. We're not a "please build me a script" kind of site.

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to write me a script. I'm just asking is there any option for this. If the only way to do it is to write the VBA macro, that is the answer as well.

Comment: That was basically what I was saying yes. The only way is a VBA macro.